# Как в React заставить код над return() выполняться после того, как исполнится код внутри return()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Нужно, чтобы код над `return()` выполнялся **после** того, как будет отрисовано DOM-дерево, описанное внутри `return()`. Вот пример кода, где DOM отрисовывается позже, что приводит к ошибкам как раз по той причине, что во время выполнения кода у программы не было информации о DOM-элементах.

```
import React from 'react'

const Test = () => {
    var x = true
    var y = 2
    document.querySelector('.abcd').innerHTML = 'Goodbye'
    function plusplus(n) {
        if (x) {
            console.log(n+y)
            console.log(document.querySelector('.abcd').innerHTML)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="abcd" onClick={() => plusplus(5)}>Hello</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Test
```

Пробовал брать код над `return()` и засовывать его в различные "волшебные" функции, которые, судя по гуглению, должны были запускать исполнение кода после отрисовки DOM. Например, пробовал помещать код в функцию `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {ЗДЕСЬ КОД}, false);` Однако мне это никак не помогло.

Comment: Чтобы чем-то помочь, необходимо понять, что именно необходимо реализовать. Например: "Мне необходимо, чтобы сначала было Hello, потом после выполнения функции писалось Goodbye". Тогда это пишется совсем по другому. В целом реакт позволяет работать без обращения к дом дереву и очень редко нужно прямое обращение, как в вашем примере.

Comment: @grad Код над return был написан в качестве примера. Суть вопроса в том, чтобы заставить это работать без ошибок. Потому как сейчас, если это запустить, то в консоль обязательно вылетит ошибка _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')_ и это потому что код пытается выполнится до того, как отрендерится страница.

Comment: Пример был специально написан таким образом. Лично у меня над return() написана логика работы слайдера, а в самом return() находится дерево реакт элементов этого слайдера. Но кода там больше, а суть такова, что если данный экспериментальный код отработает без ошибок, то и настоящий тоже так отработает.

Comment: Если слайдер самописный, то и следует его писать через ref если необходимо обращение в dom дерево. И проверять в месте своей логики на наличие ref. Если они есть, то отработает без ошибок, если не отработает, значит будет ждать, пока появится.

Comment: @grad, а можно, пожалуйста, увидеть реализацию на примере моего тестового кода. Я пытался понять, что это за штука такая "рефы", научился их определять в коде, но и с ними у меня по прежнему вылетает та самая ошибка, обозначающая, что я пытаюсь задать или прочитать свойство у элемента, который еще не был отрисован на странице.

Comment: Из вашего примера кода непонятно, как должна работать функция и в какой последовательности

Comment: @grad, вообще, можно и упросить код: нужно, чтобы вначале рендерилась страница с элементом `<div className="abcd" onClick={() => plusplus(5)}>Hello</div>`, после чего у этого элемента менялось свойство innerHTML на 'Goodbye'. Фактически, когда пользователь посетит эту страницу, то вряд ли он вообще успеет увидеть, что на странице было сообщение Hello, он увидит там Goodbye. Я планирую использовать это для того, чтобы я мог в коде получать свойства у элементов или даже сами элементы и использовать их в коде в функциях, которые сработают после того, как пользователь перейдет на страницу.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-goodall-jekruh?file=/src/App.js пример показа Hello, затем Goodbye

Comment: Спасибо, по итогу я выбрал для себя вариант с применением componentDidMount(). Пришлось проштудировать немного реакт, чтобы узнать о такой вещи как "методы жизненного цикла".

Comment: хук [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) исполняется после

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если через функциональный компонент, то может помочь хук useEffect. Но как и правильно заметили выше, такой функционал можно и нужно, реализовать без обращения к дом напрямую.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

const Test = () => {
  let x = true
  let y = 2
  function plusplus(n) {
    if (x) {
        console.log(n+y)
        console.log(document.querySelector('.abcd').innerHTML)
    }
}

  useEffect(()=> {
   
    document.querySelector('.abcd').innerHTML = 'Goodbye'

  })


    return (
        <div>
            <div className="abcd" onClick={() => plusplus(5)}>Hello</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил свой вопрос при помощи `componentDidMount(){/*Записанный внутри код будет выполнен после того, как отрисуется DOM.*/}`

Comment: ты используешь функциональные компонент, у него нет `componentDidMount`

Comment: Это да, согласен. Мне пришлось переписать его на классовый. Ранее я просто не знал о componentDidMount().